# Angular.js ngModelController contenteditable directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My Code for directive (some parts edited for security):

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('contenteditable', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '?ngModel'
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) return;

        ngModel.$render = function() {
            element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
            scope.$apply(read);
        });

        read(); //Init

        function read() {
            var html = element.html();
            if( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>') {
                html = '';
            }
            ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

This should allow me to edit a field in a form and it change however it just blocks the form all together.

UPDATE:

HTML Snippet:

```
  <form class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <label ng-model="field">{{ field }}</label>
    <input contenteditable type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{field}}" ng-model="field">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have a HTML snippet of how you are using this?

Comment: can you be more explicit about how it "blocks" the form also including a punkr or jsfiddle will help